# PHP prepare statement login

Tags: php, encryption, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to user php mysqli prepare statement for a login system. But my login function is not working. I am not sure how to retrieve the encrypted password from database and use it for autentication.

Here is my login function that handles authentication

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");


       $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

      $stmt->execute();
      $dbpwd =  $stmt->bind_result($encrypted_password)->fetch();




    if (checkhashSSHA($dbpwd, $password) {

        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }


}'
```

Here is my Decryption function

```
public function checkhashSSHA($dbString, $password) {
$pieces = explode("$", $dbString);

$iterations = $pieces[1];
$salt = $pieces[2];
$old_hash = $pieces[3];

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("SHA256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 0, true);
$hash = base64_encode($hash);

if ($hash == $old_hash) {
   // login ok.
   return true;
}
else {
   //login fail
   return false;
}
```

}

And for reference this the encryption function I am using

```
public function hashSSHA($password) {
$algorithm = "pbkdf2_sha256";
$iterations = 10000;

$newSalt = mcrypt_create_iv(6, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$newSalt = base64_encode($newSalt);

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("SHA256", $password, $newSalt, $iterations, 0, true);
$toDBStr = $algorithm ."$". $iterations ."$". $newSalt ."$". base64_encode($hash);

// This string is to be saved into DB, just like what Django generate.
return $toDBStr;
```

}

I am little bit confused with prepare statements. All I want to know is how I can retrieve the encrypted password stored in database ? So that I can pass it as a parameter to my chechhashSSHA function.

Comment: Make life easy for yourself, use the recomended mechanism for hashing and checking passwords i.e. `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: It'd be easier if you removed `bind_result()` and just fetched the password to run your comparison against.

Comment: Maybe the password isn't the first column in the result set? You could change `SELECT * FROM...` to `SELECT hashedPassword FROM...` and put in the name of your password column, and it should work.